# Regex to pull out quoted text

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use regex to identify quotes in a string with the words between them.  I also would like to include both double quotes and single quotes.

Example, If I had a string:

```
The "cat and the hat" sat on a rat.  The 'mouse ran' up the clock.
```

Then it would identify the following:

```
cat and the hat
mouse ran
```

What would the regex be?

Comment: Can there be escaped quotes: `'"This isn\'t fun!", complained O\'Malley.'`?

Comment: PHP regexes are PCRE, so you should be fine. The surrounding syntax looks a bit different than Perl’s, but the solution should still work.

Comment: Let’s just pretend there aren’t any escaped quotes. It can still be done, but it is definitely ickier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(["']).*?\1`

Works for me. Assuming that quotes can't exist inside quotes...

Comment: That needs `(?s)` is there might be line-breaks in the string. Also, you gave the user the thing with the quotes still around it, and they asked for it without the surrounding quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, how would you take the quotes out.

Comment: Mine didn’t leave the quotes in: just use `$+{guts}` as I suggested.

Comment: @tchrist Yeah, I just realised that. I'm having a play with non-capturing groups and lookaheads/behinds but it's failing on phrases like `The "cat and the hat" sat on "a rat"` where I match `cat and the hat`, `sat on` and `a rat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;

my $quoted_rx = qr{
    (?<quote> ['"] )  # SO highlight bug "'
    (?<guts> 
       (?: (?! \k<quote> ) . ) *
    )
    \k<quote>
}sx;

my $string = <<'END_OF_STRING';
The "cat and the hat" sat on a rat.  The 'mouse ran' up the clock.
END_OF_STRING

while ($string =~ /$quoted_regex/g) {
     say $+{guts};
}
```

Each time you match, the quote-type will be in `$+{quote}` and the stuff in between them will be in `$+{guts}`.

That only works for U+27 (APOSTROPHE) and U+22 (QUOTATION MARK). If you want it to work for things like ‘this’ and “this”, you’ll have to be fancier.  There is a `\p{Quotation_Mark}` property for any sort of quotation mark, and `\p{Pi}` for initial punctuation and `\p{Pf}` for final punctuation.

Comment: would this be the same in php

Comment: The pattern would be the same, but the loop would be different.

Comment: I am testing it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it does not seem to be picking them up.  I am putting in the following. qr{(?<quote> ['"] )(?<guts>(?: (?! \k<quote> ) . ) *)\k<quote>}ix;

Comment: Oh, it’s not called `qr{}` in PHP.  (And it should be `sx` for pattern flags, not `ix`; I typo'd.) I meant that the contents were the same. Sigh. Please don’t make me learn PHP just so I can explain PHP to you. You are the one programming in it. :(

Comment: Well, I didn’t realize it was PHP when I wrote it. The pattern should be fine, but I don’t know the mechanics of PHP. I was hoping that you could put the pattern into PHP faster, which you already know, faster than I could learn PHP to tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'The "cat and the hat" sat on a rat.  The \'mouse ran\' up the clock.';
preg_match_all('~([\'"])(.*?)\1~s', $s, $result);
print_r($result[2]);
```

output (as seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/pc4In)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat and the hat
    [1] => mouse ran
)
```

`preg_match_all` saves all the match results in an array of arrays. You can change how the results are arranged, but by default the first array contains the overall matches (`$0` or `$&`), the second array contains the contents of the first capturing group (`$1`, `$2`, etc.), and so on.

In this case `$result[0]` is the complete quoted strings from all of the matches, `$result[1]` is the quote, and `$result[2]` is whatever was between the quotes.